# SONY KDL-55W808C doesn't recognize SAMBA shares

Tags: linux, network-shares, android, samba, tv

I was wondering if anyone in the Superuser community was able to get SONY's KDL-55W808C Android 5.x TV to recognize and connect to SAMBA shares using stock apps, like e.g. Video.

In my setup SAMBA is running on Arch Linux and is working well with other apps on the same TV, e.g. ESFileExplorer, ARCHOS Video Player, even the stock Video app can actually easily and very reliably stream video files off a SAMBA share provided the initial connection to a SAMBA share is facilitated by ESFileExplorer.

Unfortunately, Video and other stock apps like Album or Music don't seem to recognize SAMBA shares on their own so the problem is that yes Video, for example, streams the files just well but never seems to be able to discover any shares.

The same stock Video app does see Windows shares when my gf's notebook is powered up.

I already eliminated firewall from the equation. It looks like my configuration should be ok. Just about any other device works with this SAMBA setup well.

So, I was wondering if anyone here managed to discover and connect say from the stock Video app to a SAMBA share on their Linux or UNIX server.

Comment: Please read the android tag.

Comment: This is "a question about the device interacting with your computer."